# Cassandra: Column Families for complex queries?

Tags: nosql, cassandra, bigdata, non-relational-database

Every source tells me that supporting complex queries in cassandra is complicated and you usually need to create a new `Column Family` to support specific queries (like JOINS in a relational database).

I don't understand why you would actually need another Column Family for a query.

An example of this was demonstrated by IBM here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-apache-cassandra/

The system has `Books` with the following columns: `Author`,`Price`, `tag1`, `tag2`, `tag..`.

If I wanted to perform a query like "Get all authors that have written books with the tag sci-fi", they recommend creating a column family called `TagsToAuthor`. Why is this necessary. I believe you can do the following 2 solutions without creating a new column family:

- Create a `Tag` column family, with the columns: `Book1`, `Book2`, `Book...`, `Author1`, `Author2`, `Author...`
- Create a `Tag` column family & create a `BookTag` column family that contains the columns: `book_id` & `tag_id`. Although Cassandra doesnt have a join functionality, you can simply get the tag id from the `Tag` column family, then get the list of book_id's by querying `BookTag`, then using those id's to query `Book`. Just like you would in a normal relational database.

What are the disadvantages to these solutions?